# How can I rewrite this JavaScript line for simpler reading? ( Ternary Operator )

Tags: javascript

Hi I'm trying to learn JavaScript using this Calendar code as study/project material.  There are so many things going on in this variable it's like looking at some alien language.  How can I rewrite this line for simpler reading?

https://codepen.io/xmark/pen/WQaXdv

```
// Last day of the Previous Month.
// , lastDayOfLastMonth = ...
var lastDay_of_LastMonth = m == 0 ? new Date(y-1, 11, 0).getDate() : new Date(y, m, 0).getDate();
```

Comment: That syntax is a ternary statement and reads fine. You could replace it with an if else or write a function for the lastDay_of_LastMonth. Also it is best to use const when possible instead of var. getDate is a little redundant.

Comment: seems a bit off .. for January (m == 0) it gets the number of days in November (30) instead of December (31) ?

Comment: yup it's a bug .. the calendar shows December 30th before January 1st, instead of December 31st

Comment: tnx @JohnOttenlips I will look into "const vs. var" when I get more experienced with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Month can be negative, so `new Date(y-1, 11, 0)` is same as `new Date(y, -1, 0)` :

```
var lastDay_of_LastMonth = new Date(y, m || -1, 0).getDate();
```

but to get the number of days in December when month is January (m == 0), the correct version is just:

```
var lastDay_of_LastMonth = new Date(y, m, 0).getDate();
```

Comment: Hi Slai, is this how my new code can look like?

    // Last day of the Previous Month.
    var lastDay_of_LastMonth

    if (m == 0)
    // BUG!?  It counts last day of Nov instead of Dec.
    // lastDay_of_LastMonth = new Date(y-1, 11, 0).getDate();
    lastDay_of_LastMonth = new Date(y, m, 0).getDate();
    elselastDay_of_LastMonth = new Date(y, m || -1, 0).getDate();
    }

Also I don't really understand how the "m AND -1" part applies to Feb to Dec?  Shouldn't it be "m-1" for Feb to Dec?

Comment: @Abby I mentioned it in the comments that the other versions are wrong because they get December 30 instead of December 31. You don't need else, just `var lastDay_of_LastMonth = new Date(y, m, 0).getDate();` is enough. `m-1` is not needed, because the `0` day gets the last day of the previous month. In `new Date(y, m, d)`, month starts from 0 for January, but day starts from 1

Answer (score 2):

To keep from repeating yourself, you can write `getDate` only once by creating the `new Date` in a ternary operator itself, and then call `getDate` on the whole expression:

```
var lastDay_of_LastMonth = 
  (m === 0 ? new Date(y-1, 11, 0) : new Date(y, m, 0))
  .getDate();
```

But you might also define a standalone variable for the `date` object in question instead, to make it clear what it represents:

```
var lastMonthDate = m === 0
  ? new Date(y - 1, 11, 0)
  : new Date(y, m, 0)
var lastDay_of_LastMonth = lastMonthDate.getDate();
```

Don't be afraid of separating out long expressions onto multiple lines

Answer (score 1):

The ternary operator (or compressed if) can get messy very quickly when its components have many parts. Maybe some will disagree, but it is nice to keep the ternary operator limited to simpler cases such as `var parity = x % 2 === 0 ? "even" : "odd"`

In your case, I think it would be most readable to write the whole if statement out:

```
var lastDay_of_LastMonth
if (m == 0)
  lastDay_of_LastMonth = new Date(y-1, 11, 0).getDate();
else
  lastDay_of_LastMonth = new Date(y, m, 0).getDate();
```

Comment: I disagree, this is very repetitive.

Comment: @brendon-boldt
This was more nicer to read and maintain, less complications for my brain. :)

Comment: I am not saying that this is the very _best_ way to write this out, but I do think it is the easiest to understand and the easiest to read quickly.